# Как написать if условие где число сравнивается с несколькими числами?

Tags: php

Мне необходимо определить $response больше 0 но не больше 0.3 и наоборот $response меньше 0 и не меньше -0.3, как это реализовать в if?

Неужеле нужно делать что-то подобное?

> if($response == 0 || $response == -0.01 || $response == -0.02 || $response == -0.03 ..... || ..... $response == -0.3){

Comment: а почему вы пишете равенство, если у вас не больше/меньше в вопросе?

Comment: `-.3 <= $responce and $responce <= .3`

Comment: Не знаю как иначе ограничится заданными числами от 0 до 0.3 и от 0 до -0.3

Comment: я написал во втором комментарии - оно?

Comment: Похоже оно, буду тестировать, спасибо.

Comment: вам бы надо книжку почитать, ваше представление, что от -.3 до 0 только два числа -.2 и -.1 очень далеки от реальности :(

Comment: у меня в примере не 3 числа )

Comment: это мало что меняет :(

Comment: вроде описано условие `abs($x) <= 0.3` ?

Comment: так и сделала в итоге, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-.3 <= $responce and $responce <= .3
```

можно заменить 1 условием:

```
abs($response) <= 0.3
```

если нужно после еще определить какому промежутку принадлежит, то вот:

```
 if(abs($response) <= 0.3){
      if($response < 0 )
        echo 'response от -0.3 до 0';
      elseif($response > 0)
          echo 'response от 0 до 0.3';
      else
        echo 'response = 0';
 }
```